# Image paths wrong on site in subdirectory using a .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I was able to setup a drupal site in a sub directory. I have the .htaccess file in the sub directory with a rewrite base set to /subdirectory

Everything works except when I have a image in the html, its still looking in public_html instead of public_html/subdirectory

Do I need to do a rewrite rule or..?

Update: This is my code.

```
RewriteBase /subfolder/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: show us the code in your .htaccess file where you have written rewrite base

Comment: You need to make sure that your references to the images are correct. You can use absolute paths (`/subdirectory/image.png`) or you can set the [base tag](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+base+tag) and use relative paths (`image.png`).